# Ruby On Rails Error when running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

When i run rake db:migrate i get this error:

rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Any suggestions?

This is my database.yml file:

Comment: show your database.yml file

Comment: i think your postgres server is running in different port instead of 5432. please check this and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rails application is trying to connect to the database, by using the configuration that you have on config/database.yml

It seems that you have configured a connection to a PostgreSQL but that the rails application cannot connect so it throws that error.

Check that you have the right credentials on config/database.yml and make sure postgresql is running.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get the error like this check if something went wrong as:

Probably the host is not added.

Adding **host** to database.yml file -

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_development
  username: myuser
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_test
  username: myuser
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_production
```